# how create TextBox in a cell of table in document .docx using apache poi

Tags: java, textbox, apache-poi

I used Javafx and

I created a table using apache poi:

```
 XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
 XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
 XWPFTable table = document.createTable(4, 3);
```

and created the paragraph like the paragraph below:

```
XWPFParagraph p1 = table.getRow(0).getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0);
XWPFRun r1 = p1.createRun();
r1.setText(category_number.getText() + category.toString());
```

Now, I want create a TextBox in a one cell of a row but don't know how address Cell and Row to a textBox and set text and alignment textBox.

Please Help me ):

Comment: doesn't look releated to javafx - how is it?

Comment: setText input is a component of javafx

Answer (score 1):

A text box in a `*.docx` is a shape in the document content. Creating shapes is not yet implemented in `XWPF`. But it can be done using the underlying `ooxml-schemas` classes.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTxbxContent;

import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup;
import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CreateWordTextBoxInTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(4, 3);

  // table header row
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++ ) {
   paragraph = table.getRow(0).getCell(c).getParagraphArray(0);
   if (paragraph == null) paragraph = table.getRow(0).getCell(c).addParagraph();
   run = paragraph.createRun(); 
   run.setText("Column " + (c+1));
  }

  // get run in cell for text box
  XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(1).getCell(1);
  paragraph = cell.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  

  // create inline text box in run
  // first crfeate group shape
  CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();

  // now add shape to group shape
  CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.setStyle("width:100pt;height:36pt");
  // add text box content to shape
  CTTxbxContent ctTxbxContent = ctShape.addNewTextbox().addNewTxbxContent();
  XWPFParagraph textboxparagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctTxbxContent.addNewP(), (IBody)cell);
  textboxparagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  XWPFRun textboxrun = textboxparagraph.createRun();
  textboxrun.setText("The TextBox content...");
  textboxrun.setFontSize(10);

  // add group shape as picture to the run
  Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();

 }
}
```

This code was tested using `apache poi 4.0.1` and needs the `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` in class path.

Comment: Thanks so much, my problem was solved , your skill is amazing, Thanks so much.